# React-Select NPM vs Github files don't match even though version #s do

Tags: reactjs, webpack, npm-install

On Github it sais it's up to date with version `1.0.0-rc` (https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)

On NPM it is showing version `v1.0.0-rc.5` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select) does the .5 make the difference at the end?

I need the github version because this version uses ES6 classes.

However, when using the command `npm install react-select` (even after first doing an uninstall) I do not have the matching github version.

I do get the latest files by installign via github URLs:

`npm install git+https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select`

Hoewever, when building my entire project via `webpack`, it sais it can't resolve `react-select` which 100% exist on my `node_modules`. Why can't it find the module? It doesn't give me this error when installing via `npm install react-select`

I was thinking maybe I still have to run npm start for this react-select project that I got from github? But when running it, but before installing gulp I got this error:

`npm ERR! Failed at the react-select@1.0.0-rc.5 start script`

But wait! I had installed that exact version of `react-select` via `npm` the ordinary way earlier, but now there's some sort of file difference? And where is this start script to build it?

The real underlying issue of running npm start is that I got the error `Error: Cannot find module 'react-component-gulp-tasks'` but i'm not sure if that's important at this point and i'm running down the wrong rabbit hole.

I'm now entirely out of ideas. Even if this `react-select` came from Github and not NPM, I would want to run the github version because it uses the ES6 version I want. But webpack isn't able to recognize it, and inside my github's download there's no react-component-gulp-tasks file.

Comment: Do you even save the dependency in your package.json? Try `npm install -S git+ssh://git@github.com/JedWatson/react-select.git#v1.0.0-rc.5`

Comment: I feel like some sick joke is being played on me. For some reason git+ssh isn't working.

Comment: I hit enter prematurely:
      `npm install -S git+https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select.git` downloads the most recent code and webpack can NOT run it.

    `npm install -S git+https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select.git#v1.0.0-rc.5` is compiled by webpack but somehow it is NOT the most recent files????? This makes absolutely no sense since it is the most recent version in github and yet, the files do not match the github.

edit: trying to put in code blocks

Answer (score 0):

The latest published version (1.0.0-rc.5) which is the one that exists in NPM don't use ES6 classes. The ES6 classes version is the master one (you can see the several pull requests regarding the [conversion to ES6](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ES6%20is%3Aclosed).

If you want to use the master you can set the following in your package.json file:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "react-select": "git://github.com/JedWatson/react-select.git",
    ...
}
```

This way the `nmp install` will take the files directly from github and not from the published version in npm.

Comment: Ok, but from this, master doesn't compile with webpack. I get Can't resolve 'react-select'

Comment: I manged to compile it without any problem. What/where is the error you got there?

Comment: When installing via `npm install -S git+https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select.git`  rather than including a specific version, I get

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-select' in 'path'
 @ ./General/myFile.jsx 14:19-42`

This is not an issue when using the 1.0.0-rc.5